# Does PYQT5 support all python libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am new to python and GUI programming as well.

I need to build a front-end GUI application and for the back - end application I have already built in python 2.7.

My question is, if I develop a front end application in PyQT, will I be able to integrate the python code in that (or) will the PYQT support python modules like socket, threading etc.?

Comment: You can use any of these modules, but you have to adapt your logic to the life cycle of a GUI, for example you should not have loops as a blocking True as the same GUI has a working loop, there are several alternatives, timer if the task is periodic and inexpensive, if the task is expensive a better option is to use a thread, but consider that you should not update the GUI from that thread, you must use signals and slots to send the data to the main thread and just there update them.

Comment: thanks for the response eyllanesc. i will keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt doesn't handle the back-end code. It is used to set up hooks so that when a user interacts with the GUI, some code is launched in Python.

In other words, yes, you'll be able to implement things like threading.

Here's an example where I'm clicking a button which has a 'hook' to launch a process. In this case, I'm launching the process in another thread so that the GUI doesn't freeze up.

```
import sys
import time
import threading
import datetime as dt
# Import from qtpy if you're running Anaconda3
from qtpy import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# Import from PyQt5 otherwise
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(500, 220)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 180, 93, 28))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 471, 141))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Start", None))
        self.label.setText(QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", "", None))


def main():
    # Continually update LineEdit with the time when the button is pressed
    # We can do this without freezing the GUI by launching update_time()
    # in another thread
    ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: threading.Thread(target=update_time).start())


def update_time():
    while True:
        current_time_text = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%b %d %Y %I:%M:%S %p')
        ui.label.setText(current_time_text)
        time.sleep(.01)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Changing the UI from another thread than the one the Qt main loop is running in, is a recipe for disaster because that's not thread safe.

Comment: Can you help me understand what about it is unsafe? @BlackJack

Comment: Updating the GUI from a thread that is not the main one generates problems in the dynamics of the application, read the following for more information http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html